# Fixing a dry cake batter

Tags: cake, batter

I made a chocolate cake batter last night to test for my sons birthday cake. I made a batch of cupcakes with it to test it and it came out dry. Now I’m not sure if it’s from over baking or something in the batter. Can I add anything to the left over batter at this point to save it?

Comment: Welcome! What was the recipe, or was it from a boxed mix? If we don't know what's in it, we can't know how to adjust it :)

Comment: Hello Mari and welcome! This isn't an answer, rather a suggestion. If you want to test a cake batter, make a cake layer rather than cupcakes. Some batters that work well for layers don't fare well when used for cupcakes.

Comment: Thank you! It was the cake boss chocolate decadence cake. It has melted unsweetened chocolate and buttermilk and hot water in it. Along with all the other usual chocolate cake ingredients. I figured it came out dry due to over baking a cake recipe in a cupcake. So I made another batch, and shortened the baking time, 15-20 mins opposed to 25-30 mins for the first batch and they came out better. It has a great taste so I don’t think I want to adjust the recipe.

Comment: Hey Mari, nice to see you found the likely problem. On our site, it is perfectly legit for users to answer their own questions, because this helps the next person with the same problem who stumbles upon it. You will even probably get upvotes and reputation for it, if you do it down in the large "Your answer" box and not just as a comment under the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Most commercial bakeries pour simple syrup into their cakes and cupcakes after baking. To make a simple syrup mix water and sugar in equal parts by volume and heat on the stove, stirring until dissolved. The simple syrup should keep for about a month if you have any left over.

Answer (score 0):

To save your cake batter, add milk to the batter. Also to save tour dry cake/cupcake, drizzle some sugar syrup to your cake. It will moisten it.